# Google Autocomplete move whole div

Tags: html, google-maps-api-3

I want to move or replace .pac-container, the problem is that pac-container is somwhere in deep in my HTML and i want to move whole div to my bootstrap modal, how can i do it?

```
<div class="pac-container" style="display: none;"></div>
```

My HTML

```
<body>
<div class="modal">
<input name="adress"></input>
<!-- I want to move container right here -->
</div>
<div class="container">
Blaaa
</div>
<!-- Concurent position of pac container -->
    <div class="pac-container" style="display: none;"></div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

May I guess that the main issue is that the autocomplete-input is placed in the modal and the suggestions(placed in the `.pac-container`) will appear behind the modal?

When yes: moving the `.pac-container` wouldn't help here, the result would be a incorrect position.

Try using a `z-index` for the `.pac-container` that is higher than the modal's `z-index`(currently it's 1050)

```
<style>
.pac-container{z-index:1051;}
</style>
```

Comment: My main problem is that i want a relative position to my input which is in modal and that is a problem i will edit my question so maybe you will be able to help me